# Function signature for async processing with errors accumulation

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

Suppose I've got a function `fab: A => Future[B]`. Now I need to write new function `foo` to process `Seq[A]` and accumulate all errors. That's why I cannot use [Future.traverse](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#traverse[A,B,M[X]%3C:TraversableOnce[X]](in:M[A])(fn:A=%3Escala.concurrent.Future[B])(implicitcbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[M[A],B,M[B]],implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[M[B]]) because it "fails fast" and doesn't accumulate the errors.

`foo` receives `Seq[A]` and should return a `Future`. The client should get either `B` or an exception for each element of the input `Seq[A]`. What would be a *signature* of this function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define `foo` for what you need, consider using `Future.sequence` on top of `map/recover` after applying `fab` to individual elements of the input list, as shown below:

```
import scala.concurrent.{ Future, ExecutionContext }

def foo[A, B](ls: List[A])(fab: A => Future[B])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext):
    Future[List[Either[Throwable, B]]] =
  Future.sequence(ls.map(fab).map(_.map(Right(_)).recover{ case e => Left(e) }))
```

Note that instead of `Seq`, immutable `List` is preferred hence is being used here.  Change it to `Seq` if necessary.

Testing `foo`:

```
implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.global

def fab(s: String): Future[Int] = Future{ 10 / s.length }

val ls = List("abcd", "", "xx", "")

foo(ls)(fab)
// res1: Future[List[Either[Throwable, Int]]] = Future(Success(List(
//   Right(2),
//   Left(java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero),
//   Right(5),
//   Left(java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero)
// )))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's probably what I am looking for. I just would use `Try` i/o `Either` and change the return type to `Future[List[Try[B]]]`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution with ZIO.

I added this fake function:

```
  def fab(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Int => Future[String] = i => Future(
    if (i % 3 == 0)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"bad $i")
    else
      s"$i"
  )
```

Now we create a Stream of `Int`'s and run `fab` for each of them

```
  val stream =
    ZStream.fromIterable(Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
      .map(in => Task.fromFuture(implicit ec => fab(ec)(in)))

  val sink = Sink.collectAll[Task[String]]
```

Now we collect the successes and failures:

```
  val collect: ZIO[zio.ZEnv, Throwable, (List[String], List[Throwable])] = for {
    strs <- stream.run(sink)
    successes <- Task.collectAllSuccesses(strs)
    failures <- ZIO.collectAllSuccesses(strs.map(_.flip))
  } yield (successes, failures)
```

Running and printing this:

```
  new DefaultRuntime {}
    .unsafeRun(
      collect
        .tapError { ex => zio.console.putStrLn(s"There was an exception: ${ex.getMessage}") }
        .tap { case (successes, failures) => zio.console.putStrLn(s"($successes, $failures)") }
        .fold(_ => -1, _ => 0)
    )
```

Prints us:

```
(List(1, 2, 4, 5), List(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad 3))
```

Let me know if you are need more explaining - if ZIO is an option.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to avoid external libraries, inc. `zio`, `cats`, etc.